# problems with deploying to vercel

Tags: javascript, github, next.js, solidity, vercel

I have created an app with next.js and vercel.
I am trying to deploy it and it doesn't work....
Attached image so you can see the error.

```
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for @next/swc-darwin-x64@13.4.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  x64
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-05-30T18_43_56_771Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "npm install" exited with 1
```

I have deleted package.lock.json and node.modules and i have done npm install again, and it still doesn't work....

Comment: Can you share more context?

Comment: i am deploying with vercel to have domain, but i can't because it gives me error

Comment: I understood this part. Can you share your `packages.json` ? Or any other config file to help us unterstand what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, it appears that the issue is occurring due to the package `@next/swc-darwin-x64` that's only meant for the Darwin (macOS) platform, but you're trying to run it on a Linux platform (Vercel deployment is Linux-based).

- First, you need to remove the @next/swc-darwin-x64 package from your package.json file. This package is platform-specific and is causing issues on the Linux environment.
- Then, install the @next/swc-linux-x64 package. This package should work on your Vercel Linux-based deployment.

  You can do this by running the following commands:

  ```bash
  npm uninstall @next/swc-darwin-x64
  npm install @next/swc-linux-x64
  ```
- After doing this, try to push your changes and redeploy your app.

If you don't have direct dependencies on `@next/swc-*`, you might have to look into your Next.js version or some other package that might bring in `@next/swc-darwin-x64` as a transitive dependency.

Refer to the following Vercel issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/37651